# Auto-reply to direct messages

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So I've been trying to do something so if someone dm's you, it'll reply with a message.

Example:

```
Friend: Hey

Bot: I'm afk
```

Something like that so basically when someone sends a message to your dms the bot will reply a message saying something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! What exactly is your question ? We can't seem to find it in your post

Answer (score 4):

Without breaking Discord TOS you **can't**. Because you would need to have a userbot or selfbot. Basically its some bot that acts as the user (in your case reading the messages). And most libraries are dropping the support for selfbots.
For reference: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

> Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account termination if found.

Answer (score 1):

Use `client.on` and provide a callback function as such:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('Hey'))
    target.send('im afk')
})
```