# Discord Auto Respond C#

Tags: discord

I was wondering if anyone knew how to, if possible, make a simple bot that just responds to DM's sent to you. For example, if a friend DM's you, a bot responds with something like

"This is an automated response, hang in there and I'll soon respond."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want your account to be controlled by a bot? Self bots are not authorized on Discord and can get your account banned. Bots need to be created as bots from the discord developers portal.

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered in [Auto-reply to direct messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623686/auto-reply-to-direct-messages/53730452)

It's against Discord's TOS https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Hopefully in the future, they create some small feature that just gives a basic response. Though, it is understandable why they don't want this as it could cause a lot of spam DM's and fake "people" hopping into your DM's.